# Pushing branches to github

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, github

I have local git repository on my pc with 2 branches, let's say
branch1
branch2

I have a remote github repo setup.
So far I've been working with only branch1. Now I have switched to branch 2 and have been working with it for a couple of days. I have no problem doing

```
git push origin master
```

and I receive

```
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/elijah/.ssh/id_rsa':
Counting objects: 39, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Writing objects: 100% (25/25), 2.44 KiB, done.
Total 25 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:los123/Apptwit.git
   5e6004f..7572482  master -> master
```

So things look pretty normal, it's just when I go to my github repo I:

1. see only master branch there
2. I don't see the last commit I did from branch2 (even though it was successful)

Can anybody clarify what is going on? (is it by design that I can only synch one branch with github?)
Thanks you.

Comment: change master to branch name: `git push origin master`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git push -u origin branch2`

(The `-u` sets branch2 to track github's version of branch2, like your master probably tracks github's master. Affects things like `git status` showing "you are ahead by N commits")